# CentOS 7 upgrade openssh to 9.3p2

Tags: linux, centos, openssh

I am asked for an upgrade OpenSSH version because of **CVE-2023-38408**, here is my process.:

```
yum groupinstall -y "Development Tools"
yum install -y zlib-devel openssl-devel wget

cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config  /etc/ssh/sshd_config.bak
chmod 600 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
chmod 600 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
chmod 600 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

cd /tmp
wget -c https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-9.3p2.tar.gz
tar -xzf  openssh-9.3p2.tar.gz
cd openssh-9.3p2
yum install -y pam-devel libselinux-devel

./configure --with-pam --with-selinux --with-privsep-path=/var/lib/sshd/ --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh

make && make install
```

It compiler ssh and sshd with 9.3p2 successfully in my os, so I got two versions of sshd:

- /usr/sbin/sshd OpenSSH_7.4p1
- /usr/local/sbin/sshd OpenSSH_9.3

next I shoud change /usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service execute path for the new version of sshd.

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenSSH server daemon
Documentation=man:sshd(8) man:sshd_config(5)
After=network.target sshd-keygen.service
Wants=sshd-keygen.service

[Service]
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/sshd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $OPTIONS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=42s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I switched `/usr/sbin/sshd` to `/usr/local/sbin/sshd`, and did `systemctl daemon-reload`, `service sshd restart`, but it didn't work out, the message is:

```
Aug 25 07:37:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: sshd.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
Aug 25 07:37:57 localhost.localdomain sshd[2276]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Aug 25 07:37:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenSSH server daemon.
-- Subject: Unit sshd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit sshd.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Aug 25 07:37:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit sshd.service entered failed state.
Aug 25 07:37:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: sshd.service failed.
Aug 25 07:37:57 localhost.localdomain polkitd[365]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2259:84553 (system bus name :1.46, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_
Aug 25 07:38:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: sshd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 25 07:38:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped OpenSSH server daemon.
-- Subject: Unit sshd.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit sshd.service has finished shutting down.
Aug 25 07:38:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
-- Subject: Unit sshd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit sshd.service has begun starting up.
Aug 25 07:38:39 localhost.localdomain sshd[2278]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Aug 25 07:38:39 localhost.localdomain sshd[2278]: Server listening on :: port 22.
```

Have no idea that the problem is on the file or the service config.

Answer (score 1):

You set the type of systemd service to notify, but that requires the daemon to have been built with systems support, which I at least don't see in the ./configure line.

Other than that, *you should not be doing this*. You've read somewhere that this vulnerability is bad and that you need to update your system, and do you jumped and replaced a vital part of it with something that you with zero insight replaced. You probably broke quite a few things on the way that depend on openssh and libraries, so congratulations, you're your system's worst vulnerability.

https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=80334 that thing is already patched upstream, a yum update is all that it would have taken. But now you've built the software (as root, just to make matters worse), and just randomly installed things.

So what you'll have to do is a `make uninstall`, hoping your system continues to run at that point, then a `yum update`. Luckily, this should reinstall all potentially affected parts of your openssh installation.

Comment: Actually, I told them everything you just wrote, but it's an old-school company, They only asked you to do what they say, no more resources for improvement, I tested the process in VM, so in the real world no system has been messed up, but still need to complete that..

Comment: I will try to persuade them accept update the patch from Redhat, thank you

Comment: Deam Marcus, 7.3 is ok, but I just found out one of the servers is Centos 8.5, and it seems no plan to release any patch of it, any suggestions, change OS?